# pull all posts' meta key values from current category only

Tags: custom-field

I am having trouble figuring out how to pull the meta key values for just one category. I can pull all the meta key values (for meta_key "city") in all categories no problem like this:

```
 $querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.*,$wpdb->postmeta.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id AND meta_key = 'city'";
```

but cannot figure out a way to limit it to a single category. Every time I try to modify the query above with various left and inner and right joins, I get back nothing useful.

Any ideas? Ideally it would filter by the category page we are on, but If I need to create individual category pages, I can deal with that...

Comment: and I guess I wasn't clear what my use case is: Some of these values will be repeating in posts, I just want a non repeating list of the values represented by posts in this category. ie if I have 4 posts with cities NY, SF, LA, and NY, I just want to print out a list of NY, SF, and LA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, but my PHP isn't wonderful... but I believe for someone who has some at least average php skill, this will make sense.  I cut and pasted this line from a query I am doing against a custom taxonomy myself where I only wanted it to display each term only once.

```
$terms = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $terms)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of formulating your own query, why not use WP_Query?

```
WP_Query( array('cat' => yourcatid, 'meta_key' => 'city') );
```

This would pull all the keys of City out for a given category id

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but then how do I get this list to stop repeating? For example, if I have two posts with the value "los angeles", I don't want it to be listed twice...

Comment: Are you looking for it to be dynamic or one specific post with certain meta keys? Basically for it to be dynamic or static?

Comment: dynamic (distinct) listing of all meta values (from meta_key "city") in all posts within the current (or listed) category.